# CentOS: Install git with yum says glibc requires glibc-common older than installed

Tags: centos

I'm using CentOS 6 from Docker, and when I install `git`, I get this dependency error:

```
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.i686 (updates)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.7
           Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64 (@CR/6.7)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.192.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6.x86_64 (base)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.166.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.1
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 (updates)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.3
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64 (updates)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.7

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Service 'docker-project' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yum install -y \
    java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 \
    unzip \
    git \
    && yum clean all' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This was working a few days ago without any changes. What happened to the CentOS repository?

For reference, here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos:6
RUN yum install -y \
        java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 \
        unzip \
        git \
    && yum clean all
```

Comment: Is that the epel repo is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

It will be some conflicts whenever the EPEL repo is activated. Try to install `git` using the following command:

```
yum install git --disablerepo=epel
```

You can permanently exclude git from the EPEL repositories by adding `exclude=git*` to `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` file.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the EPEL repo and `--disablerep=epel` did not help. Finally I did a `docker pull centos:centos6` and that seems to have fixed it. I guess it was a temporary problem in the image and a recent update fixed.